# Run a Javascript on page load

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to run javascript, that will set a value in the controller on page load. However, I cannot seem to get it to run.

**Visual force page**

```
   <apex:page controller="playGroundController" action="{!pageLoad}" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false">

    <header>
        <apex:form>
            <apex:actionFunction action="{!setSite}" name="setSite">
                <apex:param name="param1" assignTo="{!site}" value="GC"/>    
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <script type="javascript">
            function run(){
                console.log('hello')
                setSite('GC')
            }
            window.onload = run;
            </script>
        </apex:form>
    </header>
    <h3>
        I am text
    </h3> 


</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class playGroundController {
public string site {get;set;}

public void pageLoad(){
    site = null;
}

public void setSite(){
    system.debug('set site');
    system.debug(site);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Javascript for this functionality?

Comment: Also consider that Visualforce might have setup `window.onload` before your code runs so you may be breaking something in Visualforce you want to rely on now or later. If you really need to run some JavaScript put it inline at the end of the page which is after the DOM has been built.

Comment: It has been the only way to trigger ActionFunctions without having user input as far as I found. The goal is to set the site on the controller so the same controller can be used for multiple VF pages.

Answer (score 2):

First, you haven't specified a reRender target (even nothing), so best case scenario is that this page would infinitely reload. Also, setting window.onload *will* cause problems. Here is the minimum modified version you would want to use:

```
<apex:page controller="playGroundController" action="{!pageLoad}" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false">

    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!setSite}" name="setSite" reRender="form">
            <apex:param name="param1" assignTo="{!site}" value="GC"/>    
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
    <h3>
        I am text
    </h3> 

    <script type="javascript">
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
        function() {
            console.log("hello");
            setSite("GC");
        });
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Isn't the `DOMContentLoaded` event deprecated? I thought you were supposed to use `MutationObserver` for that event type now.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You must be thinking of something else [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) isn't deprecated.

Comment: Yeah I guess I was thinking of `DOMNodeInserted ` and other [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I added the changes. The script still does not execute. I am checking the console on the page and it never triggers.

Comment: didn't work for me either, nothing on console